# Is there any tool to represent xml hierarchy?

Tags: java, xml, spring, tree

I am currently working on a spring application, which contains a lot of xml files.
To grab the hierarchy of xml, I use to draw like this on paper:

```
main.xml ------>child1.xml---->child2.xml
         ------>chil12.xml .....
```

Now my question is, Is there any tool availablew which takes a folder path, analyzes xml files in that folder and builds a tree like the one I mentioned above?

Thanks.

Comment: "a few hundred xml files"... yikes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are those Spring configuration XML files? Then you could use the Spring IDE / STS plugin which includes drawing a dependency graph and a hierarchical view in the project explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You would have lot of Eclipse plugins for this plus there's XML Spy's Schema Editor which lot of developers use . See a similar discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473295/open-source-tool-to-generate-diagrams-from-xml-schema-documents .